# why isn't my favicon showing?Is it because of the location of my image or is it because I'm in local not in production?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm not sure why my favicon won't be shown. I followed the exact code other people use to show favicon, not anything special.
so my guess why this won't work is; location of image is wrong. or the size, type of image is wrong. or maybe because I'm still in local.
This is my folder structure and what I tried

```
----project
------------project
-------------------project
--------------------------settings
----------------------------------settings.py
-------------------template
---------------------------base.html
-------------------static
--------------------------image
--------------------------------logo.png
--------------------------css
---------------------------js
------------gitignore
------------env
-------------static
```

In my django setting

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

so here are my attempts,

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{%  static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{{static_url/favicon.png}}">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="project/project/static/image/logo.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="project/static/image/logo.png">
```

Edit

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),



]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += patterns('',) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have aws like this

```
AWS_FILE_EXPIRE = 200
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'project.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'project.utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'realproject'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'ap-northeast-2'
S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

import datetime

date_two_months_later = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(2 * 365 / 12) 
expires = date_two_months_later.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y 20:00:00 GMT")

AWS_HEADERS = { 
    'Expires': expires,
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400',
}
```

Is this blocking my static setting maybe?in production and in local, css and javascript works. and I can post image through admin. but only not in static way(I drag photo to the folder and trying to display that image)

Comment: Try just `<link rel="icon" href="...">`.

Comment: 1. Why do you have two `static` directories?, 2. Where is the favicon actually located?, 3. You should be using the `{% static %}` tag, rather than hard-coding paths.

Comment: @rnevius thank you very much for the reply, 1.I have two static directories because one is for collecting static and the other for local. but I must did something wrong because when I do python manage.py collectstatic, files in the inner static folder aren't getting collected. I have deployed my app using amazon,(for storage amazon S3 I have static and media folder correctly) 2.currently my favicon is located in inner static folder-image-folder. 3.yes I'm using <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}"> but this won't do. can you please help me?

Comment: Is there any problem just making the favicon indexable? If you have a top level static directory anyway then adding that to your URL routing means you could have access from your HTML. Do other static files work with the static block tag, or is it just the favicon that doesn't work?

Comment: @MichaelFourre other images don't work as well

Comment: Okay well that defines the problem then. Can you post your urls.py? What you should do when you're in DEBUG mode is add the "staticfiles_dir" to urls, just to make sure that it works. Otherwise you know that the path is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelFourre, hmm ok so static_root is where static files are getting collected and staticfiles_dir is for when it's in debug=true. but the main question is, when I do python manage.py collectstatic static files aren't getting collected but media files do. also why can't i upload pic, seems like I set everything right to me

Comment: @MichaelFourre I must've set static root wrong...

Comment: Maybe. Your project directory is not typical for Django so it's hard for me to say what the settings should be

Comment: @MichaelFourre really...I followed django tutorial...can you please help me thorugh chat? media folder works but static folder aren't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107302/discussion-between-em-four-and-michael-fourre).

Comment: The only thing I'd suggest is to take a look at your os.path.join call to make sure you're ending up with the right path. For example for media you use .dirname but you don't use it for static. Try a few print statements to check your paths and compare them with the real path. You could just be using the wrong path.

Comment: for media, every thing works so I just did same thing but it's not working for some reason....

Answer (score 1):

You should display fav icon with the following tag:

```
<link rel="icon" href="demo_icon.png" type="image/png">
```

the rel attribute must be equal to "icon" in order to work.

Make sure that your icon size is 16x16 or 32x32 and if it is still not working then a suggest that you should run "./manage.py runserver" and check the output to find the error

Answer (score 0):

according to your setting, the file path should be '/project/static/image/logo.png' instead of '/project/project/static/image/logo.png'

and in the template it should be {static '/image/logo.png'}
don't forget to load static in the template first

Comment: wait,,no...I thin this isn't the reason because settings.py isn't there. I have edited the question with where setting file is

Comment: your project doesn't seem like it's generated by django-admin.py..... the settings.py should be under your /project/project dir or it might not work properly

Answer (score -1):

It's not because of local project. You can see favicon even if your project is not live/ not hosted.

I think you have added wrong link type.
It should be "img/ico"

Try with this code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="img/ico"/>
```

Add your image path in href.